# Unable to convert scraped list of dictionaries to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape tables from the following website:

https://www.rotowire.com/betting/mlb/player-props.php

Data for each table is within a script on the site starting with `data: [{ ... }]`. This can be pulled using a combination of BeautifulSoup and regex. I cannot seem to convert this data into a Pandas DataFrame and it only reads it in as a single row. The data is read in as a list of dictionaries and looks as follows:

```
[{"gameID":"2513620","playerID":"13902","firstName":"Mark"}, 
 {"gameID":"2512064","playerID":"12450","firstName":"Mike"},
 {"gameID":"2513053","playerID":"14261","firstName":"Will"}]
```

This should work with `pd.DataFrame(df)`, but it does not seem to read correctly when scraped from the site.

I have tried the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re
import json

url  = 'https://www.rotowire.com/betting/mlb/player-props.php'
page = requests.get(url, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)

# Read first table
script = str(soup.findAll('script')[4])
data   = re.findall(r'data: \[(.*?)\]', script)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
                                                   0
0  {"gameID":"2513620","playerID":"13902","firstN...
```

Comment: You data is text, it needs to be read in by either casting it to a `dict` say via the `json` package or by using `pandas.read_json()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re
import json

from requests.packages import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

url  = 'https://www.rotowire.com/betting/mlb/player-props.php'
page = requests.get(url, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# Read first table
script = str(soup.findAll('script')[4])
data   = re.search(r'data: (\[.*?\])', script)

df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(data.group(1)))
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
    gameID playerID firstName lastName             name team   opp                                                                  logo                                      playerLink draftkings_onehit draftkings_twohit draftkings_onehomerun draftkings_onerbi draftkings_onesb draftkings_pitchwin fanduel_onehit fanduel_twohit fanduel_onehomerun fanduel_onerbi fanduel_onesb fanduel_pitchwin mgm_onehit mgm_twohit mgm_onehomerun mgm_onerbi mgm_onesb mgm_pitchwin pointsbet_onehit pointsbet_twohit pointsbet_onehomerun pointsbet_onerbi pointsbet_onesb pointsbet_pitchwin
0  2513620    13902      Mark  Mathias     Mark Mathias  PIT   HOU  https://content.rotowire.com/images/teamlogo/baseball/100PIT.png?v=6     /betting/mlb/player/mark-mathias-odds-13902               115                                    1000              -115                                                -115            600                                                                        None       None           None       None      None         None             None             None                 None             None            None               None
1  2512064    12450      Mike   Zunino      Mike Zunino  CLE   NYY  https://content.rotowire.com/images/teamlogo/baseball/100CLE.png?v=6      /betting/mlb/player/mike-zunino-odds-12450               115                                     700              -120                                                -105            600                                                                        None       None           None       None      None         None             None             None                 None             None            None               None
2  2513053    14261      Will   Benson      Will Benson  CIN  @ATL  https://content.rotowire.com/images/teamlogo/baseball/100CIN.png?v=6      /betting/mlb/player/will-benson-odds-14261               110                                     900              -120                                                -140            410                                                                        None       None           None       None      None         None             None             None                 None             None            None               None
3  2513620    15016     Jason    Delay      Jason Delay  PIT   HOU  https://content.rotowire.com/images/teamlogo/baseball/100PIT.png?v=6      /betting/mlb/player/jason-delay-odds-15016               110                                    1000              -115                                                -135            460                                                                        None       None           None       None      None         None             None             None                 None             None            None               None
4  2514026    15672   Geraldo  Perdomo  Geraldo Perdomo  ARI   MIL  https://content.rotowire.com/images/teamlogo/baseball/100ARI.png?v=6  /betting/mlb/player/geraldo-perdomo-odds-15672               110                                                      -135                                                -155            380                                                                        None       None           None       None      None         None             None             None                 None             None            None               None
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why using `re.search().group(1)` works while `re.findall()` does not? I also tried it with `json.loads()` but was unsuccessful. Just trying to learn when I should use one method over the other.

Comment: @StuSztukowski [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) will return a list of all matches - which you don't want, you want to return first match only (that's what `re.search` does). To access the match, I used capturing group `(...)` and used `.group(1)` to access the matched string in this group.